# Probability of choosing a particular number with the digits having probabilities assigned to them

Tags: probability

Given a set of numbers from from 0 to 999999999. I have a container with lets say 10000 numbers in the same format as in the set.

I take out a number from my set. Each of the digits has a probability assigned to it as a measure if the digits are really the one I chosen.

With what probability can I say that the number I chosen from the initial set is in the container?

The thing with this problem is that I could pull a number from the set which has lets say low probabilities for the corectness of the digits. If it is in the container though, it would create a hit. Not sure how I can put those probabilities of each digit into the calculation. Any ideas?

Comment: This is very unclear. What exactly do these digit "probabilities" measure? "If the digits are really the one I chosen" does not explain it. How exactly are these probabilities being assigned?

Comment: I see. Lets say I have a program that reads out numbers from the set. But it is not 100% sure about if it read it correctly and thus assigns a probability to each describing the uncertainty if the digit is correct.